# Can I send email message using Swift Mailer on xamp localhost

Tags: php, sql, ajax, laravel, swiftmailer

Is it possible to send email using **Swift Mailer** library on your **XAMPP** localhost instead of hosting the site?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want a solution in Laravel, because of your tags.

Laravel is already using the SwiftMailer library, so you can just work with the [Laravel Mail functions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail). In your `config/mail.php` / `.env` you can set the mail driver to smtp / sendmail and add the auth data.